# Why does 'mv' not need '-r' to work with directories, but 'rm' and 'cp' do?

Tags: linux, command-line

I am learning basic Linux commands. This seems counterintuitive: Why do copy ([cp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cp_(Unix))) and remove ([rm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rm_(Unix))) require the recursive option (`-R`, `--recursive`) to interact with directories, when move ([mv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mv_(Unix))) can already do so without the need?

Comment: Also how do you target a `/path` that resolves to a directory? Its either directory or file and there is the logic.

Comment: @dza do you mind explaining that a bit more I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: @alwaysconfused27938 explained in answer below by @Robert Longson when you target a directory how does it make sense to have or not have a `-r` flag? What should the effect be? That seems illogical. You move a folder as a unit incl its content hence always recursive.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

- `rm` (remove aka delete): Destroys information so if you ran it on a directory when you meant to run it on a file then you might do a lot of damage.
- `cp` (copy): Again, did you mean to copy a file? If we copy a directory it might have thousands of files in it. That might not have been what you wanted and filling your disk up is bad.
- `mv` (move aka rename): Just renames a directory, its contents are always going to remain the same so there's nothing recursive we could do here. We surely aren't likely to want to rename a directory and all its subdirectories to the same name.

Comment: I was told mv works like cut so yes it can be used to rename but it can also move the directory and its contents. 
`mkdir dir1;
mkdir dir2;
mv dir1 dir2/dir3;        #changes name of dir1 and moves it
ls dir2;
dir3
`
For rm that seems kind of silly reason to me as files can be important as well but still dont prompt. And to my knowledge linux doesnt have a recycle bin to retrieve files so its not like you can recover files mistakenly deleted with rm. I thought that what the -i parameter is for.

Comment: Also for cp maybe I'm misunderstanding but I dont believe thats an option. You can only copy the directory itself and all its content. 
when I try without the -r I get an error
`mkdir dir1;
cp dir1 dir2;
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory 'dir1'`

Comment: Yes this question is regarding directories, not files.

Comment: For mv, I'm not sure how the file system works, but if it just changing the address like changing a pointer and nothing recursive needs to be done then I suppose that makes sense as to why it wouldnt need -R as you wouldnt need to change the subfolders/files pointers well other than maybe properties for full path but that might be calculated after the fact. I suppose this might be more of a file library question then.

Comment: @Robert I mostly agree with you, but still there is a small inconstency there: when the source and the destination of a `mv` are on different filesystems, what happens under the hood is `cp` + `rm`. Still, '-r' is not required.

Comment: @PierU find a sufficient old version of mv and you'll get the EXDEV (Invalid cross-device link) error. Newer versions just handle this error by behaving like cp+rm. The rational is explained in POSIX1.2017: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/mv.html#tag_20_82_18 "There is no -R option to confirm that moving a directory is actually intended, since such an option was not required for moving directories in historical practice. Requiring the application to specify it sometimes, depending on the destination, seemed just as inconsistent."

Comment: @alwaysconfused27938 You’re correct, a move operation on a POSIX-like system (regardless of whether it’s a file, or directory, or socket, or device node) is just a couple of metadata updates conceptually equivalent to updating a few pointers.

Comment: It should be noted that `mv` can delete data. In fact, it can delete data the user just wrote to the disk! The maintainers are refusing to recognize this as a bug but basically what you do to reproduce it is that you move a directory to a different file system and while it's moving the data you add new files to the directory (or any of its sub directories). It then becomes a matter of luck whether that file will still be around on any file system after the moving process terminated. It does not even print a warning informing you that it just deleted your data.

Comment: I don't believe this explanation. `rm` and `mv` have equal potential for destruction, if you copy file X over file Y you lose file Y. At least when you type `rm` you certainly meant to destroy something.  And if you accidentally copy something massive you can always kill the process before it has created excessive amounts of data. @Anon's answer is way more plausible.

Comment: @Clumsycat: `mv` and `rm` have equal potential for destruction of a single file, but only `rm` can destroy a whole directory tree. `mv dir1 dir2` leaves you with `dir2/dir1`, after a failed `rename(dir1, dir2)` system call and then successful `opendir` / `renameat` system calls, within the same filesystem.  I agree, though, that damage potential doesn't seem like the most direct explanation, and agree that Anon's answer is better, as is John Dallman's new answer.

Answer (score 62):

From a basic perspective for a directory:

- `rm` has to recurse into the directory and call `unlink` and `rmdir` for every single file and directory
- `cp` has to recurses into the directory to read and then rewrite every single file and directory into a new location
- `mv` just has to do a single call to `rename`

Since there is no recursive operation to implement `mv` for a directory it does not have a `-r` option.

Unlike the other answer that focuses on damage or time taken by `rm` or `cp` the actual reason is that it's just a leaky abstraction of the implementation of these commands.

Comment: This makes sense, until one realizes `mv` to another filesystem is `cp`+`rm`. It may be `mv -r` is not a thing because we don't want to expose the inner mechanics to the user. In case of a single filesystem your reasoning stands, `mv` does not need `-r`. My guess is: in case of moving to another filesystem we want `mv` to do the expected job when called in exactly the same way.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that cross-filesystem mv is something that came much later.

Comment: @plugwash A.B linked to https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/mv.html#tag_20_82_18 describing that addition to the POSIX standard in _2018_. So yes, quite a lot later than the original `mv` (though nonstandard implementations that did it prior to 2018 certainly existed).

Comment: @KRyan I have been using `mv` across filesystems for years, if not decades... So my impression is that non standard implementations were widely available.

Comment: The addition to the standard just means that `mv` is *required* to allow cross-filesystem renames to be compliant, not that no version of `mv` before ever had that feature. Once a feature is proven to be common or popular enough, it may be added to the standard in order to make the holdouts implement the feature as well :)  (For example, I believe arrays are intended to be added to the POSIX shell specification Any Day Now.)

Comment: @PierU: Yeah, absolutely.  POSIX being that late to the party probably just means that at least a few systems had an `mv` that wouldn't copy/delete across filesystems.  GNU coreutils `mv` has been doing it for decades, probably from the beginning of that part of the GNU project.  And I assume BSD's has as well, probably also many of the popular commercial Unixes like Solaris.  Pretty sure KRyan kind of meant that with a wink, as a joke, because we all know that `mv` has worked across filesystems on the systems most of us use for *way* longer than POSIX 2018.

Answer (score 6):

This makes more sense with a little information on how filesystems work.

A directory is, in fact, a type of file. Its contents are the names of the files in that directory, and information about where to find them on the disk.  That information is stored in terms of the disk, not the directory.

When you `mv` a directory, you are only moving *the directory itself*. The files stay exactly where they were, and nothing is done to them. Therefore, there's no need to recurse into the directory. The files within it "move" with it, naturally and automatically.

Yes, it's more complicated if you're moving stuff between disks. The commands are largely designed for simple cases and have extra machinery behind the scenes to handle the complicated cases.

Comment: That's the best answer because it explains the important bit of behind-the-scenes: Directories are (conceptually) just special files; you used to be able to `cat` them.